# ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 178608 into shape (1,224,224,3)

Tags: opencv, deep-learning, face-recognition

I'm trying to get real-time face recognition for a trained VGG16 model(It has 6 classes). When I tried, I got the above error. These are my codes.

```
from PIL import Image
from tensorflow.keras.applications.vgg16 import preprocess_input
import base64
from io import BytesIO
import json
import random
import cv2
from keras.models import load_model
import numpy as np
from keras_preprocessing import image

model = load_model('FAceRec.h5', compile=False)
face_cas = cv2.CascadeClassifier('haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml')

def face_extr(img):
    faces = face_cas.detectMultiScale(img, 1.3, 5)
    
    if faces is ():
        return None
    
    for (x,y,w,h) in faces:
        cv2.rectangle(img, (x,y), (x+w, y+h), (0,255,255), 2)
        cropped_face = img[y:y+h, x:x+w]
        
    return cropped_face


## web cam 
video_cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
while True:
    _, frame = video_cap.read()
    
    face = face_extr(frame)
    if type(face) is np.ndarray:
        face = cv2.resize(face, (244, 244),3)
        face = face.reshape(1, 224, 224, 3)
                
        img = Image.fromarray(face, 'RGB') 
        
        img_array = np.array(img)
        
        img_array = np.expand_dims(img_array, axis=0)
        pred = model.predict(img_array)
        print(pred)
        
        name = "No Matching"
        
        if(pred[1][1]>0.5):
            name = "Suhail"
        cv2.putText(frame, name, (50,50), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX, 1, (0,255,0), 2)
        
    else:
        cv2.putText(frame, "No Matching Face", (50,50), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX, 1, (0,255,0), 2) 
        
    cv2.imshow('Result', frame)
    k=cv2.waitKey(1)
    if k==ord('q'):
        break
         
video_cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

can someone please help me to figure this out. even when I change the reshape with (244,244,3) it shows the same error again and again. Can somebody explain why its happening and how to solve this?

Comment: The mistake is in resize call. There must be  cv2.resize(face, (224, 224))

Comment: Third argument of resize is not a number of channels. Check resize doc.

Comment: Converting from numpy to PIL and then back to numpy, what does it for? I believe it is possible to use predict on face after reshape.

Comment: ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 178608 into shape (1,224,224,3) - I got this error after changing my code like 


 face = face_extr(frame)
    if type(face) is np.ndarray:
        face = cv2.resize(face, (244, 244))
        face = face.reshape(1, 224, 224, 3)  
        pred = model.predict(face)
        print(pred)